Implementing Navigation in Avalonia with MVVM Community Toolkit
I'm trying to implement a simple navigation which is just a MainWindow with a ContentPresenter on top of it. Most of the code is autogenerated. I only added a ContentPresenter, bound its content to a CurrentPage and created a view and a viewmodel for a home page
MainWindow.axaml
All of the code is autogenerated except the ContentPresenter
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        ...>

    <Design.DataContext>
        <!-- This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
             to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs) -->
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Design.DataContext>

        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />
</Window>

MainWindowViewModel.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace AvaloniaApplication5.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private ViewModelBase _currentPage = new HomeViewModel();
    }
}

HomeView.axaml
A blank UserControl file that should work as a page that ContentPresenter navigates to
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             ...>
    Welcome to Avalonia!
</UserControl>

HomeViewModel.cs
namespace AvaloniaApplication5.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
    }
}

The result of this code should be a display of HomeView.axaml in ContentPresenter but in reality it can't find HomeView.axaml
There's also a ViewLocator that resolves the view that corresponds to a specific ViewModel. This file is entirely autogenerated
ViewLocator.cs
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Controls.Templates;
using AvaloniaApplication5.ViewModels;
using System;

namespace AvaloniaApplication5
{
    public class ViewLocator : IDataTemplate
    {

        public Control? Build(object? data)
        {
            if (data is null)
                return null;

            var name = data.GetType().FullName!.Replace("ViewModel", "View", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            var type = Type.GetType(name);

            if (type != null)
            {
                var control = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(type)!;
                control.DataContext = data;
                return control;
            }

            return new TextBlock { Text = "Not Found: " + name };
        }

        public bool Match(object? data)
        {
            return data is ViewModelBase;
        }
    }
}

It seems like the ViewLocator does indeed work as intended and ContentPresenter wants to display HomeView but it can't find it.
I tried specifying Data Context for HomeView but it didn't do anything
HomeView.axaml.cs
public HomeView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new HomeViewModel();
}



Did you add the ViewLocator to the Application.DataTemplates?

Yes, it was there by default

It's open bug in creating user control template Namespace is missing Views ... the ViewLocator is depended on naming convention
solution
correct the namespace
HomeView.axaml.cs
using Avalonia.Controls;

namespace AvaloniaApplication5.Views; // <<< make sure that name space Has Views

public partial class HomeView : UserControl
{
    public HomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

HomeView.axaml
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="AvaloniaApplication5.Views.HomeView"> 
             <!--namespace hase Views  ....^^^^^... -->
  Welcome to Avalonia!
</UserControl>

